# HTML link for my logo is appearing in the drop down content of the adjacent button in my navbar

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar that includes a company logo and several buttons with drop-downs for different departments. All buttons and drop-downs work fine except for the one adjacent to the logo. The "Customer Service" drop-down content (this button is adjacent to the logo) is also including the HTML link for the logo. Basically, I need to completely separate the logo from the "Customer Service" button. The HTML code provided is only for the logo and the "Customer Service" button. I can provide more if needed. I'm new to this so any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
CSS:

.navbar {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: black;
border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}

.navbar a {
float: left;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
}

#logo {

height: auto;
width: auto;
max- height: 40px;
max-width: 200px;
float: left;
}

.dropdown {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
font-size: 18px;
border: none;
outline: none;
color: #D0D0D0;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
font-family: Times New Roman;
margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn   {
background-color: black;
color: orange;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #DCDCDC;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
float: none;
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}



HTML:

<body>



<div class="navbar">

<a href="weblink.com" target="_blank"><img id="logo" img src="MYS                       Logo.jpg" alt="MySite"</a>


<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Customer Service
</button>


<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="https://link1.com" target="_blank">Link 1</a>
<a href="https://link2.com/login" target="_blank">Link 2</a>

</div>

</div>
```

I expect the link from my logo to only work when clicking on the logo.

Comment: you are missing the end `>` on your img tag for your logo

Comment: That worked! Thank you..

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that each element you open you have to close it

you get

```
<style>
.navbar {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: black;
border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}

.navbar a {
float: left;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
}

#logo {

height: auto;
width: auto;
max- height: 40px;
max-width: 200px;
float: left;
}

.dropdown {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
font-size: 18px;
border: none;
outline: none;
color: #D0D0D0;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
font-family: Times New Roman;
margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn   {
background-color: black;
color: orange;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #DCDCDC;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
float: none;
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
</style>

<body>



    <div class="navbar">

        <a href="weblink.com" target="_blank"><img id="logo"  src="" alt="MySite"></a>


        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Customer Service</button>


            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="https://link1.com" target="_blank">Link 1</a>
                <a href="https://link2.com/login" target="_blank">Link 2</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```